Why does "pontoon" sound so uncommon or foreign?
Yes, I know "cartoon" sounds like normal English.
But why does "pontoon", which rhymes with it, sound somewhat odd?: Somehow the accent on which syllable combined with choice of vowels and consonants... I don't know. Or is it just me? Yes, nothing wrong with the etymology...
Or maybe because we learn pontoon much later than we learn cartoon.

Or simply  because pontoon is much less common than cartoon!

Nearly any word can seem weird if you long contemplate it apart from what it signifies. But yes, maybe it is just you, and when you learned the word. I take it you did not grow up in the Land of 10,000 Lakes, where the word in question signifies an immensely popular type of motorized watercraft.

Sounds no odder than poltroon  or latrine  :-)

There are a few words ending in 'toon'. Cartoon and platoon are the most common ones. Also, pontoon has 'o' in the first syllable which is also rare in words ending in 'toon'. The BrE and AmE pronunciations of pontoon are different also. BrE: /pɒnˈtuːn/ pon-TOON, AmE: /pɑnˈtun/ pahn-TOON

@ermanen That's true of all dictionary entries for words containing /ɒ/, e.g. pond.

Don't forget baboon.

Same thing happen to you with any or all of: tycoon saloon racoon maroon lagoon gazoon cocoon caroon cacoon bazoom baboon Walloon typhoon rattoon rangoon puccoon platoon monsoon lampoon harpoon gossoon gorsoom galloon festoon dragoon buffoon bostoon bassoon Barsoom balloon tenoroon spontoon spittoon spadroon shalloon shagroon quadroon poltroon picaroon octoroon macaroon ducatoon doubloon terceroon saskatoon quintroon puftaloon pantaloon musketoon frigatoon coquetoon Brigadoon barracoon Scandaroon?

I think words like balloon, buffoon, and bassoon are often considered a bit comic. It's the "oo" sound more than anything else - also toot, poo, moon, loon, spoon, etc (all have featured prominently in comedy).

Yes, they all refer to  rather goofy things. But maybe I spoke too soon.

If you look at the Ngram chart for pontoon with smoothing disabled, you'll notice there's a massive spike starting around 1861, and then an equally sharp downturn starting around 1865 and continuing for a few years afterward, a trend that becomes even clearer if you zoom in on the years 1850-1890.
I doubt it's a coincidence that these correspond exactly to the years of the American Civil War (including the few years thereafter when a disproportionate amount of writing about it was being produced); I definitely associate the word with Civil War history.
I suspect that that association explains why it seems unusually old-fashioned and somewhat out of place in more contemporary works.

Probably because it is derived from the French word "pont" (for "bridge") and various Latin languages before that.
https://www.etymonline.com/word/pontoon
Not sure if cartoon is derived from cart though ;)...

Cartoon is almost from cart but not exactly. It is a borrowing from French carton or Italian cartone, and ultimately from Latin carta ('paper', 'papyrus').
